# KDB/KX appending table to a file without reading the entire file

Tags: kdb

I'm new to KDB ( sorry if this question is dumb). I'm creating the following table

```
q)dsPricing:([id:`int$(); date:`date$()] open:`float$();close:`float$();high:`float$();low:`float$();volume:`int$())
q)dsPricing:([id:`int$(); date:`date$()] open:`float$();close:`float$();high:`float$();low:`float$();volume:`int$())
q)`dsPricing insert(123;2003.03.23;1.0;3.0;4.0;2.0;1000)
q)`dsPricing insert(123;2003.03.24;1.0;3.0;4.0;2.0;2000)
q)save `:dsPricing
```

Let's say after saving I exit. After starting q, I like to add another pricing item in there without loading the entire file because the file could be large

```
q)`dsPricing insert(123;2003.03.25;1.0;3.0;4.0;2.0;1500)
```

I've been looking at .Q.dpft  but I can't really figure it out. Also this table/file doesn't need to be partitioned.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can upsert with the file handle of a table to append on disk, your example would look like this:

```
`:dsPricing upsert(123;2003.03.25;1.0;3.0;4.0;2.0;1500)
```

You can load the table into your q session using get, load or \l

```
 q)get `:dsPricing
id  date      | open close high low volume
--------------| --------------------------
123 2003.03.23| 1    3     4    2   1000  
123 2003.03.24| 1    3     4    2   2000  
123 2003.03.25| 1    3     4    2   1500
```

[.Q.dpft](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qdpft-save-table) will save a table [splayed](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/splayed-tables/#what-are-splayed-tables)(one file for each column in the table and a .d file containing column names) with a parted attribute(p#) on one of the symbol columns. Any symbol columns will also be enumerated by [.Q.en](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/splayed-tables/#enumerating-varchar-columns-in-a-table).

Comment: I think it will also first load table in memory and then append a record and again write it on disk. You can check it as this operation takes almost same memory as loading a table using get or \l. And time and space taken by operation is proportional to file size(which should have  been almost constant if it was only appending to a file).

Comment: Check out the difference between `\`:table insert` and `\`:table upsert` ... insert doesn't need to read in the table. You can have an in-memory table of distinct keys and check before insertion if you want to avoid the i/o